# How to change App Id inside Titaninum

Tags: ios, titanium

I created App Id when i am created my profile inside titaninum.

where in X-code in Summary Identifier i can change The name.

but in titaninum where do i enter or change my application App Id?

com.companyName.product

I need to set into my project for titaninum.

@thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

tiapp.xml in the root directory of you titanium project has all that. It will regenerate the info.plist in Xcode when you do a clean build.

Comment: jeff Bonness Thanks a lot! i can configure the application.